# Installshield 12: Changing the destination of a merge module at run time

Tags: merge, module, installshield

I’m trying to change the destination of a merge module at run time...

Let me explain:
I have a merge module, which its destination is set to the [SystemFolder] folder.

And I have a lot of MSI projects point to this one merge module, all pointing the merge module (Component) destination to ‘(Use merge module's default destination)’.

The Issue:
One of the MSI Projects needs to install the merge module to the ‘Common File’ location (not the systyem32 folder).

So if I change the merge module (Component) destination in the MSI project to [CommonFileFolder] nothing happens (because merge module destination is still set to [SystemFolder])

Or, if I change the merge module destination to be [TARGETDIR] and then change my merge module (Component) destination in the MSI project to [CommonFileFolder], then that works fine. But then all my other MSI projects will then install the merge module to the root drive because the other MSI projects are still pointing the merge module (Component) destination to ‘(Use merge module's default destination)’.

I can’t do these two things:
I don’t want to change every single MSI project to either [SystemFolder] or [CommonFileFolder]).

And I also don’t want to create two identical merge modules (one pointing to [SystemFolder] and the other point to [CommonFileFolder]), so I only have to change the one MSI project

Is they a way I could change the merge module destination if the MSI project is point the merge module to ‘(Use merge module's default destination)’?

For example:
If TARGETDIR = ‘(Use merge module's default destination)’ then set the TARGETDIR = [SystemFolder] Else use the [TARGETDIR]

Or is there another way I could fix this?

Thanks
BillyBobLee

Answer (score 5):

When you create the component in the merge module, leave the Destination to INSTALLDIR.

When you consume the merge module in your basic msi project ( redistributables view ) right click the merge module and select properties.  Then use the Destination drop down to configure the relationship.    The file in the merge module will now go where you tell it to.

Side note, once merged, merge modules no longer exist.  Take a look at the built MSI in Orca and you'll see that there are directory table entries that look like this ( Let's assume you configured the module for SystemFolder )

### DIR | DIR_PARENT | DefaultDir

TARGETDIR      SourceDir
ProgramFilesFolder   TARGETDIR  .:PROGRA~1|program files
ISMyCompanyDir        ProgramFilesFolder  MYCOMP~1|My Company Name
ISMyProductDir        ISMyCompanyDir      MYPROD~1|My Product Name
INSTALLDIR            IsMyProductDir      .
INSTALLDIR.SOMEGUID   SystemFolder        .

The "." represent 'current directory' or 'same as parent'.

So in this case you build up that INSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files\My Company Name\My ProductName\ and that INSTALLDIR.SOMEGUID = C:\Windows\System32

Make sense?  In this way you can consume the module in different products deploying to different locations.

Comment: This worked perfect for me, I wonder why it hasn't been marked as an answer.

Comment: It kind of comes with the territory (InstallShield tag).  It's a small niche that attracks a lot of newbies and traditional /non-setup developers who tend to not accept the advice given.  I'm one of the worlds leading experts in this subject and the top contributor on the tag and I probably only get around 1/3 of my answers accepted.  I'm glad it helped you today though!  That's all the thanks I need.

Comment: You are right @Christopher Painter. As a setup developer myself I'm really grateful you keep contributing. You've saved the day many times. Thanks!

Comment: Problem I have with this answer is that, if you want to share that merge module across features that have separate output directories, it won't work.

The relationship between merge module -> output path is 1:1. Same limitation with component.

Comment: That's not a problem with my answer.  That's a misunderstanding of how merge modules work.  A merge module is merely an encapsulated collection of components. A component can only express files for 1 directory.  For that scenario you'd need multiple merge modules with different components or you'd need to consume the same merge module into multiple installers and then chain them together using a bootstrapper